# Not able to make simple node path show up in "crumbs module"

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have read all the documentation, and I have been clicking about wildly for hours, and I have used the "debug" tab for the [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) module, and I still cannot get the simplest path to show up:

Home > Content type > Node title

It always gives me: Home > Node title

This seems a simple task. Someone please give me the steps...

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the path you want to link to for "Content type" ? Do you have e.g. a view at this url?

You need to have *something* at this url, and Crumbs needs to be able to determine a title at this url. Otherwise it won't appear in the breadcrumb.

So, what you can do:

- Create a view at path "events" or "news" or whatever.
- Let the title of the view be "Events" or "News". There are two ways to do this:

  - In the Views admin, "Page settings", click "Menu", and set it to something where you can specify a title. OR
  - Choose your favourite menu, and create a link to the Views page.
  - It is NOT enough for the view to have a title by itself. It needs to have a title in the menu/routing system. (*)
- In Crumbs "Entity parent" settings, set "events" or "news" as the parent path for the respective node type.

There are other ways to create a parent page like "news" or "events". For instance, I like to use a "page" content type with a "blockreference" field to embed a views block.

(*) Maybe I should create a plugin that uses the real page title of the View as the title of the breadcrumb link.